# Privacy policy for using a SLComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, privacy

I am about to submit my app through iTunes connect, and while filling out the information, I noticed the optional URL for the privacy policy. My app does not collect personal information from any of my users, but it does allow the user to post to Facebook using the SLComposeViewController from the social framework. Do I need to have a privacy policy if my users are able to post to Facebook from my app, but I'm not collecting information?

Answer (score 0):

You can see here the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy)

**17.4** 
Apps that collect, transmit, or have the capability to share personal information (e.g. name, address, email, location, photos, videos, drawings, the ability to chat, other personal data, or persistent identifiers used in combination with any of the above) from a minor must comply with applicable children's privacy statutes, and must include a privacy policy

**17.5** 
Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be rejected

Btw, I have an App Published and I collect the username from Facebook and I have no privacy policy and the App was approved as normal. But having the privacy policy is always recommend to avoid rejected App.